# Why does Android offer updates for all the gmail accounts on the phone?

Tags: updates

I have multiple gmail accounts on my phone and I get Market and other updates listed for each of these accounts. That is simply annoying.

How can I disable that and instead set one account as my primary account for updates and such like?

Comment: I used to have this issues on the Droid X2. It seems to have stopped with a market update, some time back. Are you using the latest market (Play Store or whatever nonsense it's now named).

Answer (score 1):

You probably used different Google accounts for different apps. Switching accounts will show different apps.

I guess all you can do is uninstall the apps from one account, change accounts to the one you would like to use and then reinstall them.